# Definition of "measurable" in context of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

For a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, we say $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable if $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F} ~\forall B \in \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field. In other words, $X$ is a random variable if $X$ is measurable.

The intuition I've gathered so far is that since we can only talk about measurable subsets of $\Omega$, we want the preimage of any set in the image of X to be measurable. However, my question is, why are we only concerned with preimages of *Borel* sets, rather than all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

(For context, my experience with measure theory is only in the view of probability theory)

Comment: Measurability is always related to two sigma-algebras, one on the source set and the other on the target set. There is no reason to chose the power set as the latter (and actually one rarely does so).

Comment: The equivalence of the two definitions seems to imply that the Borel $\sigma$-field is the largest collection of measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but I feel like that's not the case.

Comment: "The equivalence of the two definitions" What? If "the two definitions" are what I think, then they are not equivalent (and one of them is never used).

Comment: $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F} ~\forall B \in \mathcal{B}$ vs "$X$ is measurable." Do these not mean the same thing?

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is enough to be concerned about sets $\{X > a\}$ with $a$ real.

For $X$ to be considered a "random variable" we need to be able to tell whether or not it is ${} > a$ for any given real number $a$.

You can try to work with "all subsets of $\mathbb R$", but you won't get very far.  Why not use only minimal assumptions?  We do not want to use the largest possible collection of sets; that is, we do not want to make it most difficult to be a "random variable".  Instead we want to use the smallest possible collection of sets; that is, we want to make it very easy to be a "random variable".

Comment: Right, but that's exactly equivalent to the Borel-set definition above since $(a,\infty)$ is a generating set for $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: So then I guess my question is, why use Borel sets, rather than some simpler sigma-field on R? Why specifically *Borel*? What makes those sets special?

Comment: The Borel sets are not special.  Comparison with a constant, that is what is special.

Comment: Why only a constant? What about {a<X<b} or {a<X<b and c<X<d} or {c<X<d and X=4}? Sure, those can be turned into comparisons to a constant, but I can keep going and in the most general case ask about {X $\in$ S} for any S $\subset \mathbb{R}$?